# New to javascript, why is jQuery such a beast?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to javascript (functional programming is okay for me, though) and I am wondering how jQuery got away with some of the design decisions they made.  Is it just too much work to fix now or what?  For instance, there seems use of strange symbols in strings when accessing elements in the DOM or weird function definitions for $, that are forcing me to check references every other time I want to get some basic data.

Can someone point me to a learning source where I can learn all of these nuances of jQuery (jQuery's examples just don't cut it, they're too spread out)?  Maybe someone has a super good reference site/pdf for jQuery?

Thanks

EDIT:

And as a side point, in regards for learning, why the heck is the entire jquery.js file collapsed onto a single line?  It is unreadable.

Comment: How can you say "jQuery is such a beast" when you are new to JavaScript? For web developers with experience in JavaScript - jQuery is a breath of fresh air. Its hard to appreciate its brilliance without understanding the pitfalls of classic javascript.

Comment: The jQuery documentation is actually quite good. And please be more specific about what you find "strange" about jQ.

Comment: +1 RPM1984.  It's the best thing since sliced cheese and what a revolution That was!

Comment: If you understand that jQuery selectors are basically a copy of CSS selectors (with some extensions thrown in) then you should go a long way to understanding how it all fits together.

Comment: @gnucom - start with something like Sams "Teach Yourself JavaScript in 24 Hours" - once you've mastered a bit of JavaScript go back and look at jQuery. You will then see it as we see it.

Comment: @Techprister, like what is the difference between $j('#myDiv') and $j('myDiv')?  Why is the key different?

Comment: It's the DOM api that's so awful, and what jQuery takes away so much of the pain from using, not javascript itself.

Comment: you have a compressed (or minified) version, which has all code on 1 line, most spaces removed etc to keep it small and a readable version. Both files can be found on the download page from jQuery.

Comment: @x1a4, not it's not exactly the DOM API here... It's weirdness of CSS which needs a spacial syntax to describe all elements. The DOM API has 2 separates functions for getById() and getByTagName()!

@RPM1984 Actually, experienced users in JavaScript ind jQuery really awful, because it breaks pretty much all of conventional JS rules... jQuery is best for beginners, because you don't really write JavaScript anymore.

Comment: As for the why it's all in one line? because that's what programming is all about, writing one lines. But you can you can also download and use the neatly formatted developer source.

Comment: @Savageman - no idea what you are talking about, what conventional JS rules does jQuery break? All jQuery really is smart wrapper functions for existing javascript. Hence the term 'write less, do more'. In jQuery - you can do a json ajax call and bind to a control in 4 lines. try doing that in less than 20 lines in javascript - and the end result is exactly the same.

Comment: $('#myDiv') will select the DOM element with an ID of myDiv, while $('myDiv') will select any and all 'myDiv' HTML nodes (there actually is no such <myDiv /> node, but this would be great for things like `p`, `span`, `div`, `blockquote`, etc.) This is modeled after exactly like what you'd find in a CSS file; jQuery did not create this convention, it is just leveraging a commonly-known syntax.

Comment: @RPM1984 Try MooTools. ;) It looks 100x more like JavaScript than jQuery does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The strange symbols you refer to are mostly CSS selectors, the standard way to address elements on the web. jQuery could've come up with its own conventions, but decided to go with what was standard and best known.

jQuery itself is surprisingly consistent. Once you wrap your head around the jQuery style you barely have to consult the documentation; things just work as you'd think they should.

The jQuery documentation is actually quite good and includes an example with every command. It also has a large user base, so a quick search will generally answer any questions you have. Google is your friend.

I'm guessing the issue is not jQuery, but a difference in javascript style compared to languages you're more familiar with. Watch Crockford's "Javascript: The Good Parts" for a reasonable introduction to good javascript style.

http://video.yahoo.com/watch/630959/2974197

Also check out Dustin Diaz's posts, I found his early screencasts where he'd build an app and talk about what he was doing very educational:

http://www.dustindiaz.com/

Answer (score 7):

Try reading [jQuery in Action](http://www.manning.com/bibeault/), it's a really good book to get started with jQuery. Next to that you can also watch examples on jquery.com, but I did prefer the book to get started.
For JavaScript basics you can try [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp).

In the beginning I had the same problem with the $ functions etc, but after I read the book it became all clear to me, and to be honest, I wouldn't use plain JavaScript without jQuery anymore for DOM manipulation.

For your edit: you have a compressed (or minified) version, which has all code on 1 line, most spaces removed etc to keep it small and a readable version. Both files can be found on the [download page](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery) from jQuery.

Comment: I actually use jQuery instead of $, but not always

Answer (score 2):

I think [jqapi.com](http://www.jqapi.com/) is a more useful jQuery API documentation resource than [jquery.com](http://www.jquery.com)

Comment: I find this much more useful than the hundreds of silly examples they have, thank you very much for this resource!

Answer (score 1):

Compressed javascript uses less bandwidth to load up, and decreases load times. Use [js beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org) to expand it.

jQuery is the greatest thing to happen to the DOM API, which is just awful to deal with. It also handles cross-browser issues and older versions, giving them functionality they otherwise wouldn't have.

The strange symbols in selectors are from CSS, not the fault of jQuery. The selectors API is now being built into browsers, so it's worth it to understand what they mean.

Comment: you can also simple download the uncompressed 'development' version from the jquery website

Comment: That answer was more of a general 'why does so much javascript show up on one line' answer.

Interestingly, Google's closure compiler actually inserts linebreaks every 500 of so characters to get around proxies that choke or deny large, single line js files. http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/faq.html#linefeeds

Answer (score 1):

As for a functional programmer every imperative language is probably a failure in your eyes and mindbending to capture, with javascript and jquery probably on top of that list. They both have side effects all over. Jquery is really about manipulating the DOM so the side effects are the means and the goal, as opposed to proper functional programming.
If you're young enough you can still make the mind switch though :-)

Answer (score 0):

start on [jQuery Docs Main page...](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page)

Answer (score 0):

You could try some other JavaScript frameworks to find out which one suits you best.

Although jQuery is pretty cool for most people, it's not the holy grail for everyone.

Maybe it's just not "your thing".

Comment: dojo ext js mootools. I tried dojo, but switched to jquery due to market demand and ease of use and its modular structure. You start of with relative small core with all kinds of possible extensions.